# vmware workstation 12 fails to detect GPUs

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation12 on windows7 to run Ubuntu 64-bit in virtual machine. Recently it doesn't work, becasue of failaire in detecting graphic cards. I get below messages (attached images). Anyone knows how can I fix it?

[image: failure message]

Another error:

[image: another failure message]

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu ?

Comment: http://theholmesoffice.com/installing-ubuntu-in-vmware-player-on-windows/ or similar

Comment: http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Ubuntu_16_04_LTS.html

Comment: My ubuntu virtual box was fine and working, but today it doesn't work, and it gives these error messages. I dont want to install a new virtual machine because I previous one I compiled some libraries that i need them.

Comment: Did you install the vmware tools ? What error in vbox ?

Comment: Yes I installed vmware tools, I was using this vm already for a long time. But, I don't know why now I have this problem. Is there a way for recovery mode or safe mode? Because I can't get into my virtual Ubuntu at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reviewing this answer: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)
Actually it was ubuntu related problem not VMware. I just updated ubuntu packages, and problem solved.